# Cart delivery address API is failing because Authorisation header is missing

Tags: spartacus-storefront

checkoutDeliveryAddressFacade.getDeliveryAddressState() is failing in checkout page in spartacus 6.1 . I am getting 401 (Full authentication is required to access this resource). I don't see aurhorization header in request header.